# Store seek bar data

Tags: java, android, xml, store

I have a page that has a button for a new event. When that button is pressed, it opens a new activity which has a time picker, date and year picker, and seek bar which will measure priority of the event 1 2 3. I need to be able to save all this data so that later it will be displayed, AND SORTED BASED ON PRIORITY (read above again, 1 ,2 ,3). The data has to be displayed on the first page below the button. I can do the display part my self later, but I need to know how to set up the data base or what ever to be able to store these variables and sort them.

Here is the source code to all the files.

**activitymain.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_event"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_event"
        android:onClick="openeditor"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/event_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_newevent.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2.80" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/event_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/event_name" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/time_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:max="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/create_event"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_event" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Main_Activity.java**

```
    package com.osah.tao;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View new_event = findViewById(R.id.new_event);
        new_event.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.new_event:
        Intent a = new Intent(this, New_event.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;

        }

    }
}
```

**New_Event.java**

```
package com.osah.tao;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;



public class New_event extends Activity {

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newevent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_newevent, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please explain in detail.